# parameter not being submitted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, radio-button

The following is an excerpt of a rails form

```
<%= form_with(model: @usercontent) do |form| %>
```

where the following html renders a collection

```
 <div class='alert'>
    <select class='image-picker show-html'  name="ki_id" id="ki_id">
      <div class='row'>
          <div class='buttonselector'>
        <label for="usercontent_ki_id_1">
      <input class="invisi-selector" type="radio" value="1" name="usercontent[ki_id]" id="usercontent_ki_id_1" />
    <img src='/assets/ki/circle-15-1c2a221aa37a24e5b23acd7124cd47ae2a17434af589353a063633a6ef5abca6.svg'> 
    <div></div>
        </label>
      </div>
      </div>

      <div class='row'>
          <div class='buttonselector'>
        <label for="usercontent_ki_id_2">
      <input class="invisi-selector" type="radio" value="0" name="usercontent[ki_id]" id="usercontent_ki_id_2" />
    <img src='/assets/ki/aerialway-15-621960ddf5e9930f1b1102faa4ee23542e11163f48a67470f1fe245abbc27955.svg'> 
    <div></div>
        </label>
      </div>
      </div>
    [...]
    </select>
  </div>
```

However, when the user selects an item, the parameter being submitted is "ki_id"=>"0".  Where is the above structure wrong?

Comment: can you show us the rails code for that collection select

Comment: not using the collection_select, wanting to ensure the html rendered first.  there is just an if statement to ensure selection of database value is proper  `<% if @usercontent.ki_id == ki.id %>  <input class="invisi-selector" type="radio" value="1" name="usercontent[ki_id]" id="usercontent_ki_id_<%= ki.id %>" />` else value=0... and  <img src='<%= image_path(ki.file_name) %>'>

Answer (score 0):

It is submitted due to `name="ki_id"` in

```
<select class='image-picker show-html'  name="ki_id" id="ki_id">
```

Can you show the full code for the view.